# Git Branch Management: Local vs. Remote

Tags: java, git, version-control, github, branch

I merged my local feature branch “navDrawer” into my copy of the remote “dev” branch. When I sync’d “dev”, it also created a remote “navDrawer” branch. Now I have 3 remotes (master, dev, navDrawer).

How would I branch off, merge into, and sync the “dev” branch without creating new remotes for each feature I work on?

My workflow would’ve been:

```
git branch
master
* dev

git checkout -b navDrawer

git commit -am“Do work”

git checkout dev
git merge navDrawer
git push
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just only push the branch you want:

```
git push origin dev
```

This supposes your remote is called `origin` here.

You can delete a remote branch by doing:

```
git push origin :navDrawer
```

More generally, the syntax is:

```
git push <remotename> [+]<localref>:<remoteref>
```

If you omit the `localref` parameter, this tells to delete `remoteref` from remote `remotename`; if you prefix `localref` with a `+`, this tells to force the branch on the remote, since by default `git` will refuse to push to a remote if this is not a fast forward (ie, if `remoteref` is not an ancestor of `localref`).

You can also create/delete tags on the remote with this command.